# In Perl why does adding "|| die" onto a statement cause it to evaluate in scalar context?

Tags: list, perl, variable-assignment, scalar

I finally found out that my code was getting evaluated in scalar context instead of list context, even though I had () around the assignment.

- 1st question is why does adding "|| die ..." onto an expression/assignment cause it to evaluate in scalar context?
- 2nd, is there an "|| die .... " idiom/equivalent that can be used when doing a list assignment?

Here is my sample code that demonstrates the issue.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $h1 = {
    var => "1",
    bar => "1",
    baz => "1",
};

my $h2 = {
    var => "2",
    bar => "2",
    baz => "2",
};

my $ds;
$ds->{rules} = [$h1,$h2];

print "TEST1\n";
print Dumper($ds);

print "TEST2\n";
my (@processes) = @{$ds->{rules}};
print Dumper(\@processes);
print "@processes\n";

print "TEST3\n";
(@processes) = @{$ds->{rules}} || die "unable to get rules form config.. \n";
print Dumper(\@processes);
print "@processes\n";
```

Output:

```
TEST2
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'bar' => '1',
            'baz' => '1',
            'var' => '1'
          },
          {
            'bar' => '2',
            'baz' => '2',
            'var' => '2'
          }
        ];
HASH(0x25eea68) HASH(0x260b240) 
TEST3
$VAR1 = [
          2
        ];
2
```

Compare TEST2 and TEST3.  As best I can tell, simply adding the `|| die '.... '` bit onto the end changes the way the statement gets evaluated into scalar context, even though I have parenthesis around the left-hand side. **Q1**: Maybe i'm just dense, but why does that happen?

**Q2**: is there an "|| die .... " idiom/equivalent that can still be used when doing a list assignment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that this forces a scalar context is because [`||` binds stronger than `=`](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity), so

```
(@processes) = @{$ds->{rules}} || die "unable to get rules form config.. \n";
```

Is parsed as

```
(@processes) = (@{$ds->{rules}} || die "unable to get rules form config.. \n");
```

And the `||` creates a boolean context.  However perl has [a weakly binding version of `||`](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Logical-or-and-Exclusive-Or):

```
(@processes) = @{$ds->{rules}} or die "unable to get rules form config.. \n";
```

Which will get parsed the way you desire.

Comment: thanks for the response!  Is there any tutorial/whitepaper that explains this?  All the material i've come across didn't cover this caveat.  Years ago I think a perl trainer on a course recommended to always use ```||``` instead of ```or```, but I've since forgotten the explanation of why (if indeed he gave us one).  (in fact I see now that I I've been using or and || interchangeably which is obviously very dangerous..  I've edited my question to show what my code was actually doing.)

Comment: @sparco1500 I've edited some links to the documentation into the answer.

Comment: @sparco1500 - Aside from the documentation links which were added to the answer, the general rule of thumb is "use `||` for logical operations; use `or` for flow control". The same applies to `&&` and `and`.

Comment: @sparco1500, Generally, one uses `or` for flow control (`or die`, `or next`, `or return`, etc), and `||` elsewhere.